# Обновление несколько строк в sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

Помогите пожалуйста, с обновлением сразу нескольких строк. У меня таблица с данными  ,где Id это номер квартиры,а остальные столбцы информация о собственнике, но возникла проблема с обновлением данных если собственников больше одного, id квартир одинаковы, а вот строк может быть две и более. Как правильно составить запрос?

```
        # Первый собственник
        nom = self.lineEdit.text()
        fam = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        imya = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        otch = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        tel = self.lineEdit_5.text()
        adres = self.textBrowser.toPlainText()
        email = self.lineEdit_8.text()
        kadastr = self.lineEdit_9.text()
        dolya = self.lineEdit_10.text()
        tarif = self.lineEdit_6.text()
        # Второй собственник
        fam2 = self.lineEdit_11.text()
        imya2 = self.lineEdit_12.text()
        otch2 = self.lineEdit_7.text()
        tel2 = self.lineEdit_13.text()
        adres2 = self.textBrowser_2.toPlainText()
        email2 = self.lineEdit_14.text()
        dolya2 = self.lineEdit_15.text()
        con = db.connect(database="Data/dom.db")
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.executemany("""UPDATE dom SET Id = ?, Fam = ?, Imy = ?, Otch = ?, tel = ?, Adres = ?, Email = ?,
                    Kadastr = ?, Doly = ?, Tarif = ? WHERE Id=%s""" % int(nom),
                        [int(nom), (fam, fam2), (imya, imya2), (otch, otch2), (tel, tel2),
                         (adres, adres2), (email, email2), kadastr, (dolya, dolya2), tarif])
        con.commit()
        con.close()
```

Как правильно обновить данные?

Comment: Исходные данные должны передаваться не в секцию SET, а в секцию WITH, где они сформируют набор записей, используемый для обновления. Набор записей должен содержать как идентифицирующую информацию (для определения, какую запись обновлять), так и информацию для обновления.